# Connecting My Website With Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, payment, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to connect my website with paypal.Have passed on the total amount which have set it in session and on running the setexpresscheckout.php i'm getting this error

`'SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message: Security header is not validShort Error Message: Security errorError Code: 10002Error Severity Code: Error'`

How can i solve this problem

This is the paypal expresscheckout.php

```
<?php
    $order_price='';
    if(isset($_POST['order_price'])){
         $order_price= $_POST['order_price'];
    }
?>
<?php

require_once ("paypalfunctions.php");

// ==================================
// PayPal Express Checkout Module
// ==================================

//'------------------------------------
//' The paymentAmount is the total value of 
//' the shopping cart, that was set 
//' earlier in a session variable 
//' by the shopping cart page
//'------------------------------------
$paymentAmount = $order_price;

//'------------------------------------
//' The currencyCodeType and paymentType 
//' are set to the selections made on the Integration Assistant 
//'------------------------------------
$currencyCodeType = "USD";
$paymentType = "Sale";

//'------------------------------------
//' The returnURL is the location where buyers return to when a
//' payment has been succesfully authorized.
//'
//' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
//'------------------------------------
$returnURL = "http://localhost/culdesign.preview/PayOrder.php";

//'------------------------------------
//' The cancelURL is the location buyers are sent to when they hit the
//' cancel button during authorization of payment during the PayPal flow
//'
//' This is set to the value entered on the Integration Assistant 
//'------------------------------------
$cancelURL = "http://localhost/culdesign.preview/PlaceAnOrder.php";

//'------------------------------------
//' Calls the SetExpressCheckout API call
//'
//' The CallShortcutExpressCheckout function is defined in the file PayPalFunctions.php,
//' it is included at the top of this file.
//'-------------------------------------------------
$resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL);
$ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
{
    RedirectToPayPal ( $resArray["TOKEN"] );
} 
else  
{
    //Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
    $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
    $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
    $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
    $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

    echo "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. ";
    echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
    echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
    echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
    echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;
}
?>
```

The code below is the paypalfunction.php

```
<?php
    /********************************************
    PayPal API Module

    Defines all the global variables and the wrapper functions 
    ********************************************/
    $PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    $PROXY_PORT = '808';

    $SandboxFlag = true;

    //'------------------------------------
    //' PayPal API Credentials
    //' Replace <API_USERNAME> with your API Username
    //' Replace <API_PASSWORD> with your API Password
    //' Replace <API_SIGNATURE> with your Signature
    //'------------------------------------
    $API_UserName="<ytech008_api1.gmail.com>";
    $API_Password="<WV6C69HAB5844H6S>";
    $API_Signature="<AAv5.GyV.pgCRwdV-5hnE5G.F8BwAs81G0tx7YR7-B6ao3PiSeCn-kvN>";

    // BN Code  is only applicable for partners
    $sBNCode = "PP-ECWizard";


    /*  
    ' Define the PayPal Redirect URLs.  
    '   This is the URL that the buyer is first sent to do authorize payment with their paypal account
    '   change the URL depending if you are testing on the sandbox or the live PayPal site
    '
    ' For the sandbox, the URL is       https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
    ' For the live site, the URL is        https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
    */

    if ($SandboxFlag == true) 
    {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
        $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    }
    else
    {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
        $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    }

    $USE_PROXY = false;
    $version="93";

    if (session_id() == "") 
        session_start();

    /* An express checkout transaction starts with a token, that
       identifies to PayPal your transaction
       In this example, when the script sees a token, the script
       knows that the buyer has already authorized payment through
       paypal.  If no token was found, the action is to send the buyer
       to PayPal to first authorize payment
       */

    /*   
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
    '       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    */
    function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL) 
    {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

        $nvpstr="&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=". $paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;

        $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
        $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

        //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        //' Make the API call to PayPal
        //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
        //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
        if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
        {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
        }

        return $resArray;
    }

    /*   
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
    '       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    '       shipToName:     the Ship to name entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToStreet:       the Ship to Street entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToCity:         the Ship to City entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToState:        the Ship to State entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToCountryCode:  the Code for Ship to Country entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToZip:          the Ship to ZipCode entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToStreet2:      the Ship to Street2 entered on the merchant's site
    '       phoneNum:           the phoneNum  entered on the merchant's site
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    */
    function CallMarkExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, 
                                      $cancelURL, $shipToName, $shipToStreet, $shipToCity, $shipToState,
                                      $shipToCountryCode, $shipToZip, $shipToStreet2, $phoneNum
                                    ) 
    {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

        $nvpstr="&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=". $paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ADDROVERRIDE=1";
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=" . $shipToName;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=" . $shipToStreet;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=" . $shipToStreet2;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=" . $shipToCity;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=" . $shipToState;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=" . $shipToCountryCode;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=" . $shipToZip;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=" . $phoneNum;

        $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
        $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

        //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        //' Make the API call to PayPal
        //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
        //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
        if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
        {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
        }

        return $resArray;
    }

    /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       None
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function GetShippingDetails( $token )
    {
        //'--------------------------------------------------------------
        //' At this point, the buyer has completed authorizing the payment
        //' at PayPal.  The function will call PayPal to obtain the details
        //' of the authorization, incuding any shipping information of the
        //' buyer.  Remember, the authorization is not a completed transaction
        //' at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize
        //' the transaction
        //'--------------------------------------------------------------

        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //' Build a second API request to PayPal, using the token as the
        //'  ID to get the details on the payment authorization
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $nvpstr="&TOKEN=" . $token;

        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //' Make the API call and store the results in an array.  
        //' If the call was a success, show the authorization details, and provide
        //'     an action to complete the payment.  
        //' If failed, show the error
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $resArray=hash_call("GetExpressCheckoutDetails",$nvpstr);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
        if($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
        {   
            $_SESSION['payer_id'] = $resArray['PAYERID'];
        } 
        return $resArray;
    }

    /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       sBNCode:    The BN code used by PayPal to track the transactions from a given shopping cart.
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    */
    function ConfirmPayment( $FinalPaymentAmt )
    {
        /* Gather the information to make the final call to
           finalize the PayPal payment.  The variable nvpstr
           holds the name value pairs
           */


        //Format the other parameters that were stored in the session from the previous calls   
        $token              = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
        $paymentType        = urlencode($_SESSION['PaymentType']);
        $currencyCodeType   = urlencode($_SESSION['currencyCodeType']);
        $payerID            = urlencode($_SESSION['payer_id']);

        $serverName         = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

        $nvpstr  = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&PAYERID=' . $payerID . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt;
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName; 

         /* Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
            If an error occured, show the resulting errors
            */
        $resArray=hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment",$nvpstr);

        /* Display the API response back to the browser.
           If the response from PayPal was a success, display the response parameters'
           If the response was an error, display the errors received using APIError.php.
           */
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

        return $resArray;
    }

    /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  This function makes a DoDirectPayment API call
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       paymentAmount:      total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCode:       currency code value the PayPal API
    '       firstName:          first name as it appears on credit card
    '       lastName:           last name as it appears on credit card
    '       street:             buyer's street address line as it appears on credit card
    '       city:               buyer's city
    '       state:              buyer's state
    '       countryCode:        buyer's country code
    '       zip:                buyer's zip
    '       creditCardType:     buyer's credit card type (i.e. Visa, MasterCard ... )
    '       creditCardNumber:   buyers credit card number without any spaces, dashes or any other characters
    '       expDate:            credit card expiration date
    '       cvv2:               Card Verification Value 
    '       
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '       
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the DoDirectPayment Call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    */


    function DirectPayment( $paymentType, $paymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber,
                            $expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, 
                            $countryCode, $currencyCode )
    {
        //Construct the parameter string that describes DoDirectPayment
        $nvpstr = "&AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCode;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CREDITCARDTYPE=" . $creditCardType;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ACCT=" . $creditCardNumber;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&EXPDATE=" . $expDate;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CVV2=" . $cvv2;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&FIRSTNAME=" . $firstName;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&LASTNAME=" . $lastName;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STREET=" . $street;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CITY=" . $city;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STATE=" . $state;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&COUNTRYCODE=" . $countryCode;
        $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&IPADDRESS=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $resArray=hash_call("DoDirectPayment", $nvpstr);

        return $resArray;
    }


    /**
      '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      * hash_call: Function to perform the API call to PayPal using API signature
      * @methodName is name of API  method.
      * @nvpStr is nvp string.
      * returns an associtive array containing the response from the server.
      '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr)
    {
        //declaring of global variables
        global $API_Endpoint, $version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;
        global $USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;
        global $gv_ApiErrorURL;
        global $sBNCode;

        //setting the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        //if USE_PROXY constant set to TRUE in Constants.php, then only proxy will be enabled.
       //Set proxy name to PROXY_HOST and port number to PROXY_PORT in constants.php 
        if($USE_PROXY)
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST. ":" . $PROXY_PORT); 

        //NVPRequest for submitting to server
        $nvpreq="METHOD=" . urlencode($methodName) . "&VERSION=" . urlencode($version) . "&PWD=" . urlencode($API_Password) . "&USER=" . urlencode($API_UserName) . "&SIGNATURE=" . urlencode($API_Signature) . $nvpStr . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . urlencode($sBNCode);

        //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        //getting response from server
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        //convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
        $nvpResArray=deformatNVP($response);
        $nvpReqArray=deformatNVP($nvpreq);
        $_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;

        if (curl_errno($ch)) 
        {
            // moving to display page to display curl errors
              $_SESSION['curl_error_no']=curl_errno($ch) ;
              $_SESSION['curl_error_msg']=curl_error($ch);

              //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
        } 
        else 
        {
             //closing the curl
            curl_close($ch);
        }

        return $nvpResArray;
    }

    /*'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Purpose: Redirects to PayPal.com site.
     Inputs:  NVP string.
     Returns: 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function RedirectToPayPal ( $token )
    {
        global $PAYPAL_URL;

        // Redirect to paypal.com here
        $payPalURL = $PAYPAL_URL . $token;
        header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
        exit;
    }


    /*'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * This function will take NVPString and convert it to an Associative Array and it will decode the response.
      * It is usefull to search for a particular key and displaying arrays.
      * @nvpstr is NVPString.
      * @nvpArray is Associative Array.
       ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      */
    function deformatNVP($nvpstr)
    {
        $intial=0;
        $nvpArray = array();

        while(strlen($nvpstr))
        {
            //postion of Key
            $keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'=');
            //position of value
            $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr);

            /*getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array*/
            $keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
            $valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
            //decoding the respose
            $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
            $nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$valuepos+1,strlen($nvpstr));
         }
        return $nvpArray;
    }

?>
```

Comment: You should post the relevant portions of your code (with obfuscated credentials, of course). Otherwise it's impossible to know what's wrong.

Comment: okey thanks let me do so

Answer (score 0):

Security header means that your API credentials are incorrect.  You need to double check your credentials, and make sure you're not sending live credentials to the sandbox server or visa-verse.  Each would have separate sets of API credentials.

Comment: Will you mind reviewing my code because it has disturbed me for more than a month,please i beg your concern

Comment: Your API credentials have <>'s at the beginning and end.  Get rid of those.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong in paypalfunction.php. No need for <>, enter your credentials in "" like following.

```html
$API_UserName="data_api1.website.domain";
$API_Password="YOURAPIPASSWORD";
$API_Signature="NeV3r.g1Ve.AwAaAY-YOUUUR.DATA-OF-SUCHTYPE-inToPublic-Forums";
```